# Why doesn't text in my pygame project blit on the screen properly? Is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have written a code just to simply receive key inputs by user and blit it to a specific part of the screen in pygame. My output looks like this:

[image: My output]

My problem is the text sometimes adds spaces in between or blits too close when I'm not pressing the space bar and just am typing random words. This is some of my code:

```
x=900

while True:

    pygame.display.update()
    events=pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            (x,y)=event.pos
            if x in data_amount_x_list and y in data_amount_y_list:
                print("Data amount hit!")
            elif x in radius_x_list and y in radius_y_list:
                print("Radius hit!")
            elif x in execute_x_list and y in execute_y_list:
                print("Execute hit!")
            else:
                print("None")
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            text=event.unicode
            myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 30)
            surface = myfont.render(text, True,(0,0,0))
            screen.blit(surface,(x,140))
            x+=15
```

Other parts of my code isn't shown because it's mostly just initialization.

Comment: It's difficult to help. Hardly things happen randomly: I bet there is a reason why sometimes you have an extra space, but the piece of code you posted does not show it. Try to notice what are you doing exactly when these extra spaces appears.

Comment: You misunderstood. It just adds spaces sometimes when I type text(I did not press the space bar) or blits too close to each other. At other times, it blits perfectly. (Check my output and see closely). And my other parts of my code are just initialization. If you want it still, ask me again

Comment: @ShobbhanPhoenixI Did you try to use a monospace font kind? In normal fonts the width of each letter is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you're experiencing depends by the kind of font you're using. In normal/proportional fonts, like the one you're using `Arial`, the characters when rendered do not use the same amount of width. In monospace fonts instead every character is guaranteed to have the same width.

The issue you're having may be resolved symply by using one such monospace fonts. Some of them are: `Consolas`, `Currier`, `Currier New`, `Lucida Console`. To do so, just edit your code like this:

```
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Currier', 30)
```

Comment: Another solution is to simply render the entire text at once every time  key is pressed instead of rendering each letter by its own.

Comment: It worked. But one problem still persists. Every time I press Caps (capital letters) or shift or alt, it adds a space in between? Any idea why, mate?

Comment: @ShobbhanPhoenix when you hit any non printable character the `unicode` property of the event object return a space. If you do not want those spaces to be printed out you should filter them out by looking at the content of the `key` property.